# Disable Scrolling on Sidebar Using Bootstrap

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, scroll, positioning

I'm new to Bootstrap and was needing help with two issues:

1. The first, is how do you disable scrolling on a sidebar? I would like the left column to be fixed to the screen and not scroll with the content on the right side.
2. Lastly, how do I move/push the content on my sidebar to the very edge of the browser window? I would also like the second column to move left with it.

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en-US">
        <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8" />
            <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
            <title>CodeButler</title>
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
            <link href="css/stylesheet.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
            <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        </head>
        <body>
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 sidebar">
                        <h1>Title of Webpage</h1>
                        <p>Some text will go here.</p>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="index.html" alt="Home">Home</a></li>
                            <li><a href="about.html" alt="About">About</a></li>
                            <li><a href="archives.html" alt="Archives">Archives</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-8 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 articles">
                        <h6>Date Here</h6>
                        <h3>Title Here</h3>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis sed mi a purus euismod dapibus at eu ante. Nunc erat risus, laoreet at elementum id, dignissim at quam. In accumsan sem a lectus vulputate, eget condimentum odio condimentum. Nulla facilisi. Duis enim dolor, tristique eu finibus sit amet, molestie vel metus. Sed a ultricies urna. Duis eget lectus vitae ligula accumsan feugiat at ut libero.</p>
                        <h6>Date Here</h6>
                        <h3>Title Here</h3>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis sed mi a purus euismod dapibus at eu ante. Nunc erat risus, laoreet at elementum id, dignissim at quam. In accumsan sem a lectus vulputate, eget condimentum odio condimentum. Nulla facilisi. Duis enim dolor, tristique eu finibus sit amet, molestie vel metus. Sed a ultricies urna. Duis eget lectus vitae ligula accumsan feugiat at ut libero.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Not clear with desired output. Can you please share the mock-up, if you have any.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have a mock up. The code Edison Arango gave me below works, however, it causes the text in the second column to overlap the text in the first column. Do you by chance know how to fix this so that the second column text shifts below the first column text when the browser window is shrunk?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To fixed the sidebar you only need to add some css to it.

```
 .sidebar { 
    position: fixed; 
    top: 0; 
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
 }
```

Comment: The above code fixes the issue. Thanks! However, when you shrink the browser window the text from the other column overlaps. Do you now how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

See if you are looking for bellow:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>CodeButler</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link href="css/stylesheet.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-4 sidebar">
                <h1>Title of Webpage</h1>
                <p>Some text will go here.</p>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="index.html" alt="Home">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="about.html" alt="About">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="archives.html" alt="Archives">Archives</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-8 articles">
                <h6>Date Here</h6>
                <h3>Title Here</h3>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis sed mi a purus euismod dapibus at eu ante. Nunc erat risus, laoreet at elementum id, dignissim at quam. In accumsan sem a lectus vulputate, eget condimentum odio condimentum. Nulla facilisi. Duis enim dolor, tristique eu finibus sit amet, molestie vel metus. Sed a ultricies urna. Duis eget lectus vitae ligula accumsan feugiat at ut libero.</p>
                <h6>Date Here</h6>
                <h3>Title Here</h3>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis sed mi a purus euismod dapibus at eu ante. Nunc erat risus, laoreet at elementum id, dignissim at quam. In accumsan sem a lectus vulputate, eget condimentum odio condimentum. Nulla facilisi. Duis enim dolor, tristique eu finibus sit amet, molestie vel metus. Sed a ultricies urna. Duis eget lectus vitae ligula accumsan feugiat at ut libero.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: getting rid of the col-md, col-sm, and col-xs didn't work

Comment: Please refer http://www.keenthemes.com/preview/metronic/theme/admin_4_material_design/ which will help you getting the fixed side bar styles.